# creating a list of functions using globals()

Tags: python

I am trying to define 3 functions.

```
one = 'one'
two = 'two'
three = 'three'
l = [one, two, three]

for item in l:
    def _f(): return '::'+item
    globals()[item] = _f
    del _f
print(one(), two(), three())
```

However, the three functions are the same, they are equal to the last one. Am I using globals() in the wrong way?

Comment: No, but `item` is just a *name* in the body of `_f`, not the current value of `item`.

Comment: Usual trick: `def _f(item=item): return '::'+item`. Or shorter `_f = lambda(item=item): '::'+item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `item` is just a name in the body of `_f`, you should define `_f` in a scope where `item` will have the value you want when you *call* the function.

You should also not try to inject values into the global namespace like this; just use an ordinary `dict`.

```
def make_function(x):
    def _():
        return '::' + x
    return _

d = {item: make_function(item) for item in ['one', 'two', 'three']}

for f in d.values():
    print(f())
```

Comment: Bah, I forgot to *return* `_` from `make_function`. I'll fix.

Comment: It works, though I see it as a different philosophy. Do you recommend accessing a list of functions through a dictionary instead of creating customized function names?

Comment: Absolutely. Variable names are *code*, not data.

Comment: Thanks. It is definitely the "safe" option.

Comment: (Regarding your edit: I had initially intended to use `print(d[f]())`, then started thinking I had a list of functions rather than a `dict` mapping strings to functions.)